# IntersectInP bug of Macaulay2

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, computational-geometry, computer-algebra

I am trying to use the intersectInP command in Macaulay2, inside package ReesAlgebra. However, I tried to follow the exact code in the user-guide, but it doesn't run in my Ubuntu app (of win 10). Can anyone explain to me which part I have done wrong ?

Here is the user-guide age (https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/Macaulay2/doc/Macaulay2-1.15/share/doc/Macaulay2/ReesAlgebra/html/_intersect__In__P.html)

Here is my code screenshots. [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no bug. You are trying to follow the documentation of a newer version than the one you are running. You should get a newer version of Macaulay2.

Comment: Thanks ! I have been using distinguished commands with 1.10, but I didn't realize that intersectInP is a new package.